# How to pass var values to a parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatable

I was trying to use 2 different tables, different input field, and different text in a single script. I use this script below to pass those values on a function parameter to get those values. The problem is I am not getting the `input.value` but I can get the `input1.value`. I think the `input1` is not going inside the `filterFunction(input)` above

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function filterFunction(table, input, total_amount_id) {
        var filter, tr, td, i, totalViewable = 0;
        console.log(input1.value);
        console.log(input);
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
            tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                    totalViewable += parseFloat(tds.innerHTML);
                    document.getElementById(total_amount_id).innerHTML = "$" + totalViewable.toFixed(2);
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var table1 = document.getElementById("dateTable");
    var input1 = document.getElementById("event_date_range");
    var total_amount_id1 = "total_amount_td";
    filterFunction(table1, input1, total_amount_id1);
    var table2 = document.getElementById("dateTable2");
    var input2 = document.getElementById("event_date_range2");
    var total_amount_id2 = "total_amount_td2";
    filterFunction(table2, input2, total_amount_id2);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input1 = document.getElementById("event_date_range");
```

In this expression you are placing value in `input1`.
so you cannot ge the {input} value.

Comment: `filterFunction(table1, input1, total_amount_id1);` that's why I was using this to change the `input` into `input1`